# input parameter used in case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following simplified stored procedure where based on on the input parameter, I need to then do a case in the where clause. It will not execute as it says: Incorrect syntax near '='

```
     PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataInfo]
     @Allowactive   BIT = 1 
     AS

     BEGIN
       Select * from tbl1 1
       where (CASE  @Allowactive
       WHEN 0 then (t.Isactive = 1) END
      AND isSubmitted = 1 
      END
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

your where clause will be like below

```
   where 
  CASE  @Allowactive
   WHEN 0 then t.Isactive  END =1
  AND isSubmitted = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use parameters in a query like this, as it messes up the query plan.  When the right plan to use changes depending on the parameter, you need separate queries, or to force SQL to always recompile.

So do this instead:

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[DataInfo] @Allowactive   bit = 1 
as
begin
    if @Allowactive = 0
    begin

        Select * from tbl1 1
        where Isactive = 1
        AND isSubmitted = 1 

    end
    else
    begin

        select * from tbl1 1
        where isSubmitted = 1 

    end

end
```

Instead run separate queries.

Comment: Using multiple execution paths like this can have some performance issues too. Gail Shaw has a great blog post about this. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: Thank you. For what you suggested, will it run faster vs. using it the way I had it.

Comment: @NatePet the way to find out which is faster is to test it on your system with your data. But be careful because changing the parameters can have a huge impact on performance for both ways.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [Zaynul Abadin Tuhin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764828/5816083) directly answers your question.
But, I believe a case statement complicates what you want to achieve.

I think a query like this satisfies your desired outcome:

```
  PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataInfo]
 @Allowactive   BIT = 1 
 AS

 BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM tbl1 t
   WHERE (@Allowactive = 1 OR (@Allowactive = 0 AND t.Isactive = 1))
   AND t.isSubmitted = 1 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following and see the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl1 AS T
WHERE CASE @Allowactive 
      WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE @Allowactive END = T.Isactive 
      AND
      isSubmitted = 1;
```

If you have 2012+ version then you could also do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl1 AS T
WHERE IIF(@Allowactive = 0, 1, @Allowactive) = T.Isactive;
```